# How to reload the components of the Polyphoria plugin in Unreal Engine 5 within the Character class for a multiplayer game without using c++?

Tags: c++, networking, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

We're programming a multiplayer  game based (its a social game with a hyper-realistic image like the old Second Life ) solely using blueprints because the net system its really simple, and using metahumans . We use Polyphoria's character builder plugin for metahumans.

And something really strange happens! We add all the components to the "Character" class (we add a subclass called BPCharacter where we put all the necessary components of the Polyphoria plugin), then we compile and everting its OK!

But then when we test the program in computers 75% of the time it loads and everything is correct but 25% it doesn't load on time! and only in clients, never in the computer that creates the sesion!

How can we reload the components in the Polyphoria Character class once the program is loaded and the network connection is started without having to recompile a version with C++ and manually force the necessary modules/components to reload? (Recompiling a project in C++ means months of work and only the polyphoria components fail!)

The problem is obvious and we see that it only occurs either on slow computers or when the connection is slow (we have tested it on more than 50 different computers and about 20 different connection lines, from fiber to 4G).

It seems obvious that in some circumstances it fails to fully load all the components implemented in BPCharacter (within the Character class). We've seen this problem happen to more people on Unreal forums. The simplest solution is to reload all the components of the class that fail. That's easy using an Unreal Engine project with C++! But with Blueprints we can't find a way! We've studied it a lot

We have optimized the scenario to the maximum, materials, instantiation, etc., disabled Nanite and Lumen, etc. In other words, it loads very fast, it is a very simple and optimized environment by levels. In fact, when the builder loads and the metahuman works, (when polyphoria components works oks, 75% of times) the rest of the game goes really perfectly! (voice and texts chat, video plugins, internet external navigation, lights, shadows, interactions, character animation, triggers, etc) So... All blueprints, components, plugins (we're talking about more than 1000!) work perfectly!... except polyphoria plugin that sometimes not load!

We've studied tons of documentation but couldn't find a method to fully recharge Polyphoria components (Maybe they charge incorrectly for some reason?). Once the network connection with Epic is established, the world is loaded with everything necessary, the game starts, the world loads, but 25% of the time the character builder does not load (obviously neither does the character, nor the option to load a previously saved character) the problem only occurs on slower computers or slow or mobile connection lines.